# How to set activeClassName for wrapper element of Link or IndexLink in react-router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, redux

I am new to the ReactJS world, and would like to know how can I pass active class name to the `<li>` element instead of `<a>(Link)` element.

Now I have this kind of code. The anchor class changes when clicked.

```
<li><IndexLink to='/' activeclassName='active'>A</IndexLink></li>
<li><Link to='/b' activeclassName='active'>B</Link></li>
<li><Link to='/c' activeclassName='active'>C</Link></li>
```

But I would like to get something similar to:

```
<li activeclassName='active'><IndexLink to='/'>A</IndexLink></li>
<li activeclassName='active'><Link to='/b'>B</Link></li>
<li activeclassName='active'><Link to='/c'>C</Link></li>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: For v4 version please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/54573453/1074944

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to enclose your `<li>` as a router aware component:

```
import { Link, IndexLink } from 'react-router'

class NavItem extends React.Component {
  render () {
    const { router } = this.context
    const { index, onlyActiveOnIndex, to, children, ...props } = this.props

    const isActive = router.isActive(to, onlyActiveOnIndex)
    const LinkComponent = index ? Link : IndexLink

    return (
      <li className={isActive ? 'active' : ''}>
        <LinkComponent {...props}>{children}</LinkComponent>
      </li>
    )
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
<ul>
  <NavItem to='/' index={true}>Home</NavItem>
  <NavItem to='/a'>A</NavItem>
</ul>
```

I took inspration from the react-router-bootstrap module, https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-router-bootstrap/blob/master/src/LinkContainer.js. I didn't test it though so let me know how it goes.

Comment: Depending on your setup, you may need `NavLi.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.object
};

export default NavLi;`

Comment: You may need to ensure your component gets the context e.g. `router: PropTypes.object.isRequired`

Comment: Instead of getting `router` through the context, use the `withRouter` HOC from `react-router` package to get the router via props.  This will also update the link's active status when the page changes, since otherwise React has no way to know if the `isActive` has changed.

Comment: `withRouter(...)` does not work for me. `this.context.router` is still undefined :(

Answer (score 19):

The other answers don't seem to work in React Router v4. Here's how you can do it:

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react'
import {Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import styles from './styles.less';

export default function NavItem({children, to, exact}) {
    return (
        <Route path={to} exact={exact} children={({match}) => (
            <li className={match ? styles.activeRoute : null}>
                <Link to={to}>{children}</Link>
            </li>
        )}/>
    )
}

NavItem.propTypes = {
    to: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    exact: PropTypes.bool,
    children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
};
```

Comment: Thank you for this. 
I would add `...props` to params and use it in `<Link to={to} {...props}>{children}</Link>` for more flexible.

Comment: i would not use the ternary operator and instead use this `<li className={match && styles.activeRoute}>` more terse.

Comment: @Sag1v I don't like using that syntax anymore. I got bit when it evaluated to `0` and I had a stray 0 in my UI. Can create even worse bugs if you're not careful.

Comment: @mpen i know what you mean, though in this case a `0` would produce the same effect won't it?

Comment: Updated jsfiddle for the answer @mpen gave above: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/99537/

Comment: This component doesn't re-render when the route changes, so it'll only become active for the first render

Comment: @Zerquix18 Sounds like a bug in your code. Did you put a `PureComponent` somewhere further up the tree perhaps? This `NavItem` is an SFC, there isn't any logic to prevent a re-render.

Comment: for react router v5 you should use ` <li className={match.path === to ? styles.activeRoute : null}>`

Answer (score 10):

```
/**
 * A navigation component
 */
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link, IndexLink, withRouter } from 'react-router'

import styles from './styles.scss'

class NavItem extends Component {
  render () {
    const { router } = this.props
    const { index, to, children, ...props } = this.props

    let isActive
    if( router.isActive('/',true) && index ) isActive = true
    else  isActive = router.isActive(to)
    const LinkComponent = index ?  IndexLink : Link

    return (
      <li className={isActive ? 'active' : ''}>
        <LinkComponent to={to} {...props}>{children}</LinkComponent>
      </li>
    )
  }
}

NavItem = withRouter(NavItem)

export default NavItem
```

Usage:

```
<ul className="nav nav-tabs"> 
  <NavItem to='/home' index={true} >Home</NavItem>
  <NavItem to='/about'>About</NavItem>
</ul>
```

Comment: Although it looks similar to Marc's answer on first glance, this answer worked better for me. `withRouter` seems to be the way in current versions to get access to the router.

Comment: This worked for me but since i was using a IndexLink i had make this one change:     else  isActive = router.isActive(to, true) . I had to add true to IsActive function or else isActive always returned true for '/'.

Comment: Did not worked: `router` is undefined for me, not found in `this.props` :-(

Answer (score 5):

```
{/* Make sure that `location` is injected into this component */}
<ul className="nav navbar-nav">
  <li className={location.pathname === '/' && 'active'}>
    <Link to='/'>
      Home page
    </Link>
  </li>
  <li className={location.pathname.startsWith('/about') && 'active'}>
    <Link to='/about'>
      About us
    </Link>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Easiest answer.

Answer (score 4):

In stead of using `<Link />`, I use `<NavLink />` and It works as well.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

//.....

export default class AppNav extends Component {

    render (){
        return (
                <header>
                    <ul className="main-nav">
                        <li><NavLink activeClassName={"active"} exact={true} to="/">Home</NavLink></li>
                        <li><NavLink activeClassName={"active"} to="/about">About</NavLink></li>
                        <li><NavLink activeClassName={"active"} to="/courses">Courses</NavLink></li>
                    </ul>
                </header>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: This fixed my issue.  I wonder what the difference is between them that makes it work?

Comment: Worked for me, no need of any workarounds, Should mark it as the best answer.

Comment: Is it setting the class of parent `<li>` element ? For me it is just setting the class of `<a>` that is created from `<NavLink>`.

Comment: This wasnt the question. He asked about parent class.

Comment: The OP wants to add the class to the parent element of the Link, not the Link itself.

Answer (score 3):

Great answer.

Just change the following to get it working...

```
LinkComponent = index ? IndexLink : Link //If its true you want an IndexLink 

//Also link needs to be...
<NavItem to="/" onlyActiveOnIndex index={true}>Home</NavItem>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with [react-router-active-component](https://github.com/insin/react-router-active-component).

I couldn't get any of the previous answers to easily work due to incompatibilities between react or typescript versions (this is definitely not a mature ecosystem), but this component did the trick, and can be applied to other elements than `li` if needed:

```
import activeComponent from 'react-router-active-component'
let NavItem = activeComponent('li');
...
<NavItem to='/' onlyActiveOnIndex>Home</NavItem>
<NavItem to='/generate-keywords'>Generate keywords</NavItem>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using react 15.1.0, react-router 2.5.0 and bootstrap 3.3 (this is less important), I developed this solution for making the links active:

`npm install --save classnames`

`npm install --save lodash`

The component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link, IndexLink } from 'react-router';
import _ from 'lodash';
import classnames from 'classnames';

class NavItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // The default state
    this.state = {
      isActive: false,
      unregisterRouteListener: false
    };

    // Binding for functions
    this.locationHasChanged = this.locationHasChanged.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Check if component is active on mount and add listener on route change
    this.setState({
      isActive: this.context.router.isActive(this.props.to, true),
      unregisterRouteListener: this.context.router.listen(this.locationHasChanged)
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.state.unregisterRouteListener) {
      // Remove the listener
      this.state.unregisterRouteListener();
    }

    // Reset the state
    this.setState({
      isActive: false,
      unregisterRouteListener: false
    });
  }

  // Update the state of the component, based on the router path
  locationHasChanged() {
    this.setState({
      isActive: this.context.router.isActive(this.props.to, true)
    });
  }

  render () {
    let { index } = this.props;
    let LinkComponent = index ? Link : IndexLink;
    let newProps = _.omit(this.props, 'router');

    return (
      <li className={classnames('', this.state.isActive ? 'active' : '' )}>
        <LinkComponent {...newProps}>
          {this.props.children}
        </LinkComponent>
      </li>
    );
  }
}

NavItem.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.object
};

export default NavItem;
```

Usage:

```
<NavItem to="/list">List</NavItem>
```

I am a beginner with React, so the above solution surely needs improvements and might contain approach errors. However, it might also contain useful information or a starting point to those interested.

Any feedback or suggestions are more than welcome. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using React Router v4.2 and I couldn't get the reference to the router object from the wrapping component, because the context is not available.

This did not work:

```js
const { router } = this.context
```

I like @mpen's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43263057/199813), but I'm using nested routes and I don't want to change the file where I have the routing component defined.

What I did is compared the location.pathname with to :

```js
const NavItem = withRouter(props => {
  const { to, children, location } = props;
  return (
    <li className={location.pathname == to ? "active" : null}>
      <Link to={to}>{children}</Link>
    </li>
  );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the reason but for me `<NavLink activeClassName="active"  to="/events"><li>Events</li></NavLink>` was not at all working.

After a lot of googling, I found a workaround with the help of `useLocation()` prop provided by the `react-router-dom.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

// Active the Link on two URLs

export default () => {
    
    // extract pathname from location
    const { pathname } = useLocation();

    return (
        <li className='Navigation__list-item'> 
            <NavLink 
                to="/events" 
                className={pathname === "/events" ? "active" : ""} >
                Events 
            </NavLink> 
        </li>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Using React Router v4, I only got it to work by including the `<li>` tags within the NavLink component.  The solutions which have the `<li>` tags wrapping the links resulted in the HOME `<li>` tag always having the `active` class.

```
import React from 'react'
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

class Header extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <header>

          <nav>
            <ul>
              <NavLink activeClassName={"active"} exact={true} to="/"><li>Home</li></NavLink>
              <NavLink activeClassName={"active"} to="/about"><li>About</li></NavLink>
              <NavLink activeClassName={"active"} to="/courses"><li>Courses</li></NavLink>
            </ul>
          </nav>

        </header>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Header
```

I adjusted the `li` and `a` CSS selectors accordingly.