# ReactJS activeClassName react-router on parent <li>

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
      <li>
        <Link activeClassName="active" to="dashboard">
          <svg height="30" viewBox="0 0 16 16" width="30" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M15.45 7L14 5.551V2c0-.55-.45-1-1-1h-1c-.55 0-1 .45-1 1v.553L9 .555C8.727.297 8.477 0 8 0s-.727.297-1 .555L.55 7C.238 7.325 0 7.562 0 8c0 .563.432 1 1 1h1v6c0 .55.45 1 1 1h3v-5c0-.55.45-1 1-1h2c.55 0 1 .45 1 1v5h3c.55 0 1-.45 1-1V9h1c.568 0 1-.437 1-1 0-.438-.238-.675-.55-1z"/>
          </svg>
        </Link>
      </li>
```

Here's an example, this works. However I want to be able to add the activeClassName onto the parent li instead. How could I accomplish that?

Comment: Did you look at this answer ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35053161/how-to-set-activeclassname-for-wrapper-element-of-link-or-indexlink-in-react-rou

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to apply activeClassName to parent `<li>` because you want all the children  to inherit the property? If so, wrap `<Link>` in a component like so: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/05-active-links#nav-link-wrappers