# Active NavLink to parent element

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using React Router v4 and I have a case where on my navigation links, I want to enable the `active` className to the `NavLink` parent element, not the `NavLink` itself.

Is there a way to access the path (`match`) even though I'm not inside the `Switch` element?

Or do I have to keep state? Because I'm feeling it's kinda missing the idea of router.

Here's my example, I want to apply the `active` className to `li` element not `NavLink`:

```
const {
  HashRouter,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  NavLink,
} = ReactRouterDOM

const About = () => (
    <article>
        My name is Moshe and I'm learning React and React Router v4.
    </article>
);

const Page = () => (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/'  render={() => <h1>Welcome!</h1>} />
      <Route path='/about' component={About}/>
    </Switch>
);

const Nav = () => (
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><NavLink exact to="/">Home</NavLink></li>
            <li><NavLink to="/about">About</NavLink></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
);

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Nav />
                <Page />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
ReactDOM.render((
    <HashRouter>
        <App />
    </HashRouter>),
    document.querySelector("#app"));
```

https://codepen.io/moshem/pen/ypzmQX

Comment: For v4 version please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/54573453/1074944

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It doesn't seem like it is very easy to achieve. I used `withRouter` HOC described in [react router docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter). It gives access to `{ match, location, history }` from `props` inside components located outside of `Routes`s. In the example I wrapped `Nav` component to get `location` and its `pathname`. Here is the example code:

```
class Nav extends React.Component {
 getNavLinkClass = (path) => {
   return this.props.location.pathname === path ? 'active' : '';
 }
 render() {
  return (
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li className={this.getNavLinkClass("/")}><NavLink exact to="/">Home</NavLink></li>
        <li className={this.getNavLinkClass("/about")}><NavLink to="/about">About</NavLink></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  )};
}
Nav = withRouter(Nav);
```

You will probably have to take care of `params` in your routes (if you have any), to match properly. But you still have to match for each path you have in your `NavLink`, which might not be pretty code. But the idea is that when the route is changed, `Nav` is rerendered and correct `li` is highlighted.

Here is a working example on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/k5p71k13k7).

Answer (score 3):

Can be achived with Route component

```
<ul>
  <Route path="/about">
    {({ match }) => <li className={match ? 'active' : undefined}><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
  </Route>
</ul>
```

Reference: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Route.md#children-func

Answer (score 1):

If you abandon the `NavLink` components altogether, you can create your own components that emulate the "activeness" of a `NavLink` by using `useHistory()` and `useLocation()` from `react-router-dom`.

#### Dashboard.js

```js
const routeItems = [
  { route: '/route1', text: 'Route 1' },
  { route: '/route2', text: 'Route 2' },
];

<Router>
  <NavBar routeItems={routeItems} />
</Router>
```

In `NavBar.js`, we just need to check to see if the current active route is the same as the route for any individual item on the

#### NavBar.js

```js
import { useHistory, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const NavBar = (props) => {
  const { routeItems } = props;
  const history = useHistory();
  const location = useLocation();

  const navItems = routeItems.map((navItem) => {
    return (
      <div style={{
        backgroundColor: navItem.route === location.pathname ? '#ADD8E6' : '',
      }}
        onClick={() => {
          history.push(navItem.route);
        }}
      >
        {navItem.text}
      </div>
    );
  });

  return (navItems);
};
export default NavBar;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found simpler solution for my case I have nested items but I know the base of each nest

for example the base of nest is `/customer` it contains items like so
`/customer/list` , `/customer/roles` ...

So did put some logic in `isActive` prop in the parent `NavLink`

code with explanation down :

```
<NavLink
to={item.route}
activeClassName={classes.activeItem}
onClick={e => handleItemClick(e, key)}
isActive={(match, location) => {
         // remove last part of path ( admin/customer/list becomes admin/customer for example )
         const pathWithoutLastPart = location.pathname.slice(0, location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/"));
              // if current parent is matched and doesn't contain childs activate it 
              if (item.items.length === 0 && match) {
                return true;
              } 
              // if sliced path matches parent path 
              in case of customer item it becomes true ( admin/customer === admin/customer )
              else if (pathWithoutLastPart === item.route) {
                return true;
              } 
              // else inactive item
              else {
                return false;
              }
            }}
          >
...
</NavLink>
```

Now parent active with his child
[image]