# react-router current route/params in navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, redux, react-router

All,

What is the recommended approach to retrieve the current state of routing?

(seeing that `react-router-redux` is not fully compatible with v4 yet)

The pattern I am using is - I imagine - a common one:

```
<MenuItem active={route === '/foo'}><Link to='/foo' /></MenuItem>
```

where `route` is a temp state derived from routing props ... however routing props like `match/history/location` routing params are not passed to the navigational components (b/c they should appear no matter what)

So, our options are

- Make the navigation a `Route` via `<Route />`
- Use redux (wait for v4 support or contribute)
- Use context (seems like a bad way to do business)

Any other more elegant options?

Comment: If you are wanting to have an active state, why not change the order so that the `Link` is the parent of your menu items (that way the whole item is a link). and use `activeClassName` on the `Link`?

Comment: That's a great idea - I can give it a try and see what I end up with, will need to think through UI framework compatibility ... but I can imagine this being a more elegant alternative

Comment: A link is just an anchor tag which should be compatible. I have done it with react mdl, react material-ui and regular custom components before. should be fairly easy to do... Also if that doesn't work you can look at this. [Might be another alternative if you extract the logic of the router here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35080727/2733506)