# highlight list item in mapped items

Tags: javascript, list, reactjs, state

I am trying to highlight the li element when it is hovered and keep it that color if it is clicked. I have only been able to do this via CSS like so:

```css
.Side-menu-link:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #27B872;
}
```

but it only does the icon and not the whole li square.

This is the parent component:

```js
export default class Nav extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='Side-bar'>
        <ul className='Side-menu'>
          <NavItems />
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is my child component with the li elements:

```js
const topNavItems = [
  {
    route: '/shoppingCart',
    name: 'shop',
  },
  {
    route: '/admin',
    name: 'key',
  },
];

export default class NavItems extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          topNavItems.map((tn) => {
            return (
              <li key={tn.name}><NavLink className='Side-menu-link' to={tn.route}><Icon name={tn.name} /></NavLink></li> //eslint-disable-line
            );
          })
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35053161/how-to-set-activeclassname-for-wrapper-element-of-link-or-indexlink-in-react-rou

Comment: @gravityplanx thanks. I was able to do the activeClassName={'active'} but that only styles the background of the navlink element, how do I get it to do the while li element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added the following CSS to fix this

```css
li.link-wrapper > a.selected{
  background-color: #27B872;
  display: block;
}
```