# css for activeClassName does not apply in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a component named NavigationItems and I have some NavLinks as follows:

```
     <ul className={classes['navigation-container']}>
        <li className={classes['navigation-item']}>
            <NavLink to="about-me"
            className={classes["navigation-link"]}
            activeClassName="active-link" exact>ABOUT ME</NavLink>
        </li>
     </ul>
```

in my css file named NavigationItems.module.css, when I want to write styles for active-link, these styles are not applied to the class active-link. Styles are as followed:

```
.active-link {
  color: blue;
}
```

The interesting thing is that activeStyle is working. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Please refer this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35053161/how-to-set-activeclassname-for-wrapper-element-of-link-or-indexlink-in-react-rou

Comment: I actually want to use activeClassName and I think its the right solution.

Comment: Hi @ShadiFarzankia! Did you finally found something? I also want to use both CSS modules and activeClassName but never achieved it :( Weird thing i that when I put the '.active-link' definition in the global CSS file (not in the xxxx.module.css file), things are working properly! Don't understand how to make it work keeping the active definition within the CSS module...

Answer (score 0):

In the same way className works:
`activeClassName={classes['active-link']}`